# Is this the simplified version of this boolean expression? Or is this reviewer wrong

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Cause I've tried doing the truth table unfortunately one has 3 literals and the other has 4 so i got confused.

```
F = (A+B+C)(A+B+D')+B'C;
```

and this is the simplified version

```
F = A + B + C
```

http://www.belley.org/etc141/Boolean%20Sinplification%20Exercises/Boolean%20Simplification%20Exercise%20Questions.pdf

cause I think there's something wrong with this reviewer.. or is it accurate? 
btw is simplification different from minimizing from Sum of Minterms to Sum of Products?

Comment: Link is now broken - please either fix it, embed the original problem statement as an image, or flag the question for deletion (since it's of no use to anyone else without the original problem statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the same.

Draw the truth table for both expressions, assuming that there are four input variables in both. The value of `D` will not play into the second truth table: values in cells with `D=1` will match values in cells with `D=0`. In other words, you can think of the second expression as

```
F = A +B + C + (0)(D)
```

You will see that both tables match: the `(A+B+C)(A+B+D')` subexpression has zeros in `ABCD= {0000, 0001, 0011}`; `(A+B+C)` has zeros only at `{0000, 0001}`. Adding `B'C` patches zero at `0011` in the first subexpressions, so the results are equivalent.

Comment: You simplify to get the SOP form right? So its also the SOP form?

Comment: @vincentbelkin I did a truth table, didn't do a simplification into a sum of products. Both tables look identical to me, with zeros at `ABCD = {0000, 0001}`, and ones everywhere else.

Comment: No I mean it is the simplified version right? So if I were to make (A+B+C)(A+B+D')+B'C; into its SOP form it would be A + B + C?

Comment: @vincentbelkin Yes, the simplified version is in the SOP form: the most primitive kind of it, where each "product" is a product of a single multiplier.

Comment: But I can't help but wonder if I should put A +B + C + (0)(D) in a test, or A+B+C, just to show that D is a literal in the expression

Comment: @vincentbelkin I don't think you should add the `(0)(D)` term, `A + B + C` is a perfectly fine answer.